# String to JSON format in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create json format from variable javascript.

```
var code="1,description 1;2,description 2;3,description 3;4,description 4";
```

I want to change to JSON Format become:

```
var result = [{"key":"1", "value","description 1"},{"key":"2", "value","description 2"},{"key":"3", "value","description 3"},{"key":"4", "value","description 4"} ]
```

I already using split but too difficult because use 2 split(split by "," and ";"). How to fix it?

Thank you.

Regards,
Bobby

Comment: `{"key":"1", "value","description 1"}` not valid

Comment: [That isn't JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @Quentin LoL. Now this is new. I know there isn't a JSON Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When parsing stuff in Javascript you usually make a regex that represents one data item and globally replace it with a function that populates some structure and pushes it into a collection:

```js
let data = [];

let str = "1,description 1;2,description 2;3,description 3;4,description 4";

str.replace(/(.+?),(.+?)(;|$)/g, (_, key, value) => data.push({key, value}));

console.log(data)
```

The reason of (ab)using `.replace` for this is that global `.match` doesn't support groups.

Comment: Man, too bad, without an explanation?

Comment: Still, no idea what you are doing! The regex is crazy, plus many (including me) don't know how arrow and spread functions work.

Comment: And don't you think using RegEx for such a small thing could be so cumbersome and overkill?

Comment: neat ! :) you could use the destruction variables direcly.

Comment: even shorter `str.replace(/(.+?),(.+?)(;|$)/g, (_, key, value) => data.push({key, value}));`

Comment: @NinaScholz: that's not "shorter", strictly speaking... ;) but yep, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note, it should be:

```
{"key":"1", "value": "description 1"}
```

You need to use multiple loops. And the process is:

1. Define final object.
2. Step one: Split on `;`.
3. Step two: Split each of the element on `,`.
4. Push everything to the final object.

**Snippet**

```js
// Define final object:
var finalArray = [];
var code = "1,description 1;2,description 2;3,description 3;4,description 4";
// Step one: Split on ;
code = code.split(";");
// Step two: Split on ,
for (var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
  code[i] = code[i].split(",");
  finalArray.push({
    "key": code[i][0],
    "value": code[i][1]
  });
}
// Let's see the output:
console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the splitted parts with a new object for the key and value properties.

```js
var code="1,description 1;2,description 2;3,description 3;4,description 4",
    result = code.split(';').map(function (a) {
        var p = a.split(',');
        return { key: p[0], value: p[1] };
    });

console.log(result);
```